# How do you rearrange a list of lists where the first element holds multiple values and creates a new list of lists while repeating the first element?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary, mapping

Given a list of lists:

```
list_format = [['a', 'c', 'f', 'b'], ['j', 'l', 'o', 'c'], ['q', 's', 'v', 'e']]
```

'c', 'f', 'b' must be mapped to 'a' 

'l', 'o', 'c' must be mapped to 'j' 

's', 'v', 'e' must be mapped to 'q'

The output should look like this:

```
[['a','c'],['a','f'],['a','b'],['j','l'],['j','o'],['j','c'],['q','s'],['q','v'],['q','e']]
```

I've tried so far:

```
list_dict = {element[0]:element[1:] for element in list_format}
newer_lst = []

for key, value in list_dict.items():
    newer_lst.append((key, value))

newer_lst
```

Gives me the output of tuples:

```
[('a', ['c', 'f', 'b']), ('j', ['l', 'o', 'c']), ('q', ['s', 'v', 'e'])]
```

I'm newer at this and trying to rearrange, any advice would be awesome, been stuck for days with trial and error(searched google countless times and constantly googling.  I feel I'm getting close but can't seem to put it together.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner, using slicing:

```
[[i[0],j] for i in list_format for j in i[1:]]
```

gives:

```
[['a', 'c'], ['a', 'f'], ['a', 'b'], ['j', 'l'], ['j', 'o'], ['j', 'c'], ['q', 's'], ['q', 'v'], ['q', 'e']]
```

Also, if you iterate through your `value` variable, you get your result:

```
list_dict = {element[0]:element[1:] for element in list_format}
newer_lst = []

for key, value in list_dict.items():
    for i in value:
        newer_lst.append((key, i))

print(newer_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a loop, just loop on sub array and append new sub array to main output array on the fly, like new_list.append([lst[0], item])

```
new_list = []
for lst in list_format: 
    for item in lst[1:]: 
        new_list.append([lst[0], item]) 
print(new_list)
#output                                                                                                                     
#[['a', 'c'], ['a', 'f'], ['a', 'b'], ['j', 'l'], ['j', 'o'], ['j', 'c'], ['q', 's'], ['q', 'v'], ['q', 'e']]
```